# On deployment System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, deployment

My program works when running on my pc in Visual Studio 2017 and when I run the executable on my pc.  But I am leaving something out when I create the setup and install it on another pc.  Any idea what it could be?

CONNECTION STRING
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\JROTC_db\JROTC_Inventorydb.accdb

QUERY.
SELECT DISTINCT BaseType FROM table1

Answer (score 0):

After further searching I found a website that had the answer.  The installer was corrupting the database file.  I just copied the file over to the target machine and it worked fine.